# "NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null" message appear when there is no "length" word in the code?

Tags: flutter, dart

I tried to make a list of Card with some data in it. I was used a snapshot.data.length for itemCount, but i get the message like in the title. So i try to change the itemCount to a static number and the message still appear. Here is my code

```
Expanded(
          child: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            child: FutureBuilder<List>(
              future: getData(),
              builder: (context, snapshot){
                if (snapshot.hasError) print(snapshot.error);
                return snapshot.hasData
                ? ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:0),
                    itemCount: 3,//snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      return PJpilihan(pj: snapshot.data, i: index);
                    }
                  )
                : Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
              },
            )
          ),
        )
```

Even when there is no 'length' word in the code(changed with static number), the message still appear.

```
I/flutter (26713): NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
I/flutter (26713): Receiver: null
I/flutter (26713): Tried calling: length
```

Answer (score -1):

Try stopping the application and restarting from scratch instead of using hot reload. I have personally experienced similar problems using hot reload and restarting the app usually solves this.

Comment: it doesn't change anything